# How to build a system app in Android AOSP 13 for /system/ directory for emulator?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to build a sample system app which lives in the `/system/app` directory.

I am building AOSP Emulator using the goldfish device for the target product `sdk_phone64_x86_64`.

The standard process as per my knowledge was to get the application code to compile in AOSP environment first, using the `Android.bp` mechanism and then use `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in a device.mk type file for the required target.

But this will cause build errors for artifact path requirement.

If I add the app name in `64bitonly/product/vendor.mk` under `device/generic/goldfish`, and compile the systemimage using make, I get an error:

```
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:30: warning:  device/generic/goldfish/64bitonly/product/sdk_phone64_x86_64.mk produces files inside build/make/target/product/generic_system.mks artifact path requirement.
Offending entries:
system/app/SampleSystemApp/SampleSystemApp.apk
In file included from build/make/core/main.mk:1352:
build/make/core/artifact_path_requirements.mk:30: error: Build failed.
16:08:03 ckati failed with: exit status 1
```

Later I did try [Enforcing Product Partition Interfaces](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/partitions/product-interfaces#step-1-create-makefile-and-enable-artifact-path-check) via [this](https://github.com/rajatgupta1998/android_device_generic_goldfish/commit/bbb4d827125a33f6d8b327a4c59178ad78d2e277) commit, but the same situation. So what is correct way to build an app in AOSP Android 13 environment which goes in `/system` partition?

Some examples include `HTMLViewer`, `Keychain`, etc.

However, I don't wish to modify [build/make/target/product/handheld_system.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/target/product/handheld_system.mk)

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Note: Adding the module name to PRODUCT_PACKAGES in `vendor.mk` works fine on Android 10 AOSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual solution is to utilise the flags

```
PRODUCT_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENT_ALLOWED_LIST+= \
    system/app/SampleSystemApp/%
```

I added in my `vendor.mk` file and compiled the system image succesfully. However, Google suggests to use `/system_ext` instead. Overall, the best way IMO to bundle system apps is to directly use product or odm partitions as per requirement.

Comment: I am adding a prebuilt apk file called BingChat.apk to packages/apps/BingChat directory and I have also created Android.bp file containing android_app_import module. But when I added above code to venor.mk app is not showing up on the emulator. I am using sdk_phone_x86_64-eng as target and which also supports emulator

Comment: Check your $OUT/installed-files.json and verify if it is getting added to the build?